Expo react-native " Main " is not registered. Invariant property violations
Hi I am using expo SDK 50 version and react-native so the error goes like whenever I am trying to open project on expo go app it is showing me those error which are like
Uncaught Error
"main" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

This is the App.js code
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";

import analytics from "@react-native-firebase/analytics";

import AppNavigator from "./Source/Navigation/AppNavigator";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import store from "./Source/store";

import { FIREBASE_TOPIC_NAME } from "./Source/Constant/ConstantApi";

import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";

import { GlobalStateProvider } from "./Source/Context/GlobalStateContext";



export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    const requestUserPermission = async () => {

      try {

        // Request notification permission

        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(

          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,

          {

            title: "Notification Permission",

            message: "This app needs access to send you notifications.",

            buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",

            buttonNegative: "Cancel",

            buttonPositive: "OK",

          }

        );

        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {

          console.log("Notification permission granted");

        } else {

          console.log("Notification permission denied");

        }



        // Request Firebase Cloud Messaging permission

        const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();

        const enabled =

          authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||

          authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

        if (enabled) {

          console.log("Authorization status:", authStatus);

        }

      } catch (error) {

        console.error(error);

      }

    };

    const subscribeToMessagingEvents = async () => {

      try {

        // Subscribe to FIREBASE_TOPIC_NAME topic

        await messaging().subscribeToTopic(FIREBASE_TOPIC_NAME);

        console.log(`Subscribed to ${FIREBASE_TOPIC_NAME} topic successfully`);



        // Print FCM token

        const printFCMToken = async () => {

          try {

            const token = await messaging().getToken();

            console.log("FCM Token:", token);

          } catch (error) {

            console.error(error);

          }

        };

        printFCMToken();



        return () => {

          messageSubscription();

        };

      } catch (error) {

        console.error(error);

      }

    };



    // Execute the initialization functions

    requestUserPermission();

    const unsubscribe = subscribeToMessagingEvents();



    // Log event for app initialization

    analytics().logEvent("app_initialized");



    return () => {

      unsubscribe();

    };

  }, []);



  return (

    <GlobalStateProvider>

      <Provider store={store}>

        <AppNavigator />

      </Provider>

    </GlobalStateProvider>

  );

}

But but when I am using react-native default template which is

import React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';



export default function App() {

  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>

      <Text>Hello, Expo!</Text>

    </View>

  );


}

Please someone help me with this
I have tried every command available on stackoverflow still it is not working on expo go.
I am trying to find a solution for my question
Uncaught Error
"main" has not been registered. This can happen if: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.


I experienced this same error and have struggled to fix this for 5 days.
I am using Expo SDK 51. The solution in this link helped me to resolve the error: registerRootComponent.
The Expo SDK requires a different way to registerRootComponent.
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
import { View } from 'react-native';
function App() {

   return <View />;

}

registerRootComponent(App);

